# NPM ERR Code E401: Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I downloaded a NodeJS application from GitHub and facing the following error when executing `npm install`.

> npm ERR! code E401
> npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/c1156c2f-a3bb-4fc4-ac07-3eab96da8d10, Basic realm="https://pkgsprodeus21.pkgs.visualstudio.com/", TFS-Federated

My Node version is 6.13.1 and NPM version is 6.13.4.
Following is the content of package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "DemoApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A social oasis for lovers of pizza.",
  "repository": "****",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "****",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/boom": "7.4.2",
    "@hapi/catbox": "10.2.1",
    "@hapi/catbox-redis": "5.0.2",
    "@hapi/cookie": "10.1.0",
    "@hapi/good": "8.2.0",
    "@hapi/good-squeeze": "5.2.0",
    "@hapi/hapi": "18.3.1",
    "@hapi/inert": "5.2.1",
    "@hapi/joi": "15.1.0",
    "@hapi/vision": "5.5.2",
    "aws-sdk": "2.488.0",
    "bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
    "bootflat": "2.0.4",
    "fs-extra": "8.1.0",
    "handlebars": "4.1.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.13",
    "pg": "7.11.0",
    "sequelize": "5.9.4"
  }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a link to the github? I supect that one of the dependencies is secured.

Comment: you aren't passing the bearer token back it seems check out this :-https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/authorization/#bearer-token

it is also applicable for react/angular or any other frontend calling apis to backend.

Comment: I just copy-pasted your package.json file to an empty directory and run `npm i` and it installed everything correctly. Could you try to do it in a clean environment? Also, what OS do you use?

Comment: Could you run 'npm whoami', if this returns something, try 'npm logout' then try npm i again

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I am using Windows 10.

Comment: @InchHigh 'npm whoami' returns following 
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in.
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek what do you exactly mean by a clean environment.Are you suggesting to uninstall Node & then install again?

Comment: @Titulum: Following is the GitHub link: https://github.com/ryanmurakami/pizza-luvrs/issues/10

Comment: @GauravAhuja No, I mean try to install those dependencies on some isolated environment in order to isolate the issue and make sure it is not connected to something specific on your OS

Comment: I tried to run `npm i --save keycloak-angular` and faced the same issue on Ubuntu 18. I get the following error: `npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/68f955b9-2bc2-436c-8ccd-adad7ff63380, Basic realm="https://pkgsprodsin1.app.pkgs.visualstudio.com/", TFS-Federated`

Answer (score 109):

First, delete the .npmrc file in your Users folder. This folder:

```
C:\Users\[your user name]
```

Then run this command in your project folder that has an .npmrc file in it:

```
npx vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc
```

Comment: Does not work in Linux (e.g. Ubuntu): `vsts-npm-auth: Exec format error`

Comment: I needed to add `-force` and then it worked for me.

Comment: Same problem, worked with `-F` this time. (Yes I googled and found to my own comment without realising it afterwards).

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10.

Comment: An explanation of what the problem is and why this solves it would be awesome for those of us who are less knowledgeable about `npm`

Comment: The command does not work on macOS.

Comment: This works on Windows. For sake of completeness, after executing the above steps, you need to run `npm install` and it probably should install all dependency packages correctly without failing.

Answer (score 62):

Use `npm install --registry https://registry.npmjs.org` instead of `npm install`

Comment: This worked for me so my problem is resolved but it doesn't address the underlying issue. There is a separate identity that is looking to an address I no longer have auth for to get this package. Do you know where I can change this?

Comment: @James check your .npmrc file under c:\users\<USER>\.npmrc

Comment: I also had a local .npmrc file with a registry definition to Github registry. This fixed it for my npm ci && npm run test command

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Comment: This should be the ideal answer - it worked for github action runner as well

Answer (score 34):

No need to delete the .npmrc file, the following worked for me

```
npm logout
```

Then

```
vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc
```

Comment: I still needed "npx" at the beginning of the second command, but this approach worked for me!

Comment: This works for me, I have recently changed my password so may be this issue happened, Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

If you get E401 with a private npm registry after upgrading to npm v7, remove your package-lock.json and reinstall.

The registry url setting in .npmrc needs to match the http/https protocol in your package-lock.json exactly.

Or as Stuart pointed out: find and replace to update the existing lock file with the correct URL

Comment: Or find and replace to update the existing lock file with the correct URL

Comment: this was it for me. wow what a ridiculous error message i would never have thought to delete the package.json!!

Comment: In my case, package-lock.json was pointing to a private registry no accesiable in my corp network. Anyway, removing package-lock.json solved it for me.

Answer (score 14):

Worked for me:

- Delete the yarn.lock/package-lock.json files
- npm install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, my discovery was as follows:

The application node.js version was **14.0**
but the node version in my machine was **16.0**.
I had to install the node the version 14.0 to resolve the issue.

To manage multiple node versions this tool is highly recommended.

- windows - [Nvm for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)
- Linux - [Nvm for Linux](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: Yes, looking in the package.json I had an npm version much older than the on my windows pc.  Using nvm (installed using CMD not powershell) I was able to also get the older one to run and then switch back for my other projects.

Answer (score 4):

I had this exactly same error and turned out it was an issue with personal access token (PAT). Renew your PAT and run `vsts-npm-auth`.

Comment: Renew your PAT?

Comment: @marz "Personal Access Token" In Azure DevOps / User Settings / Personal Access Tokens

Answer (score 4):

Delete old `.npmrc` file from user home directory and then run the following command

```
vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc -T $HOME/.npmrc
```

Comment: `npx vsts-npm-auth -C .npmrc -T %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\\.npmrc` - if you inherit a project that only supports windows >.> | You may need to `rename %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\\.npmrc %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\\.npmrc.bak` or add -force. In the $HOME/.npmrc, you may need to change //visualstudio to / h t t p s :/ /visualstudio

Answer (score 2):

I solved it running this command:

```
npm logout/npm login
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue comes from a wrong configuration in your .npmrc file. I had a slightly different error so I'm sharing it here.

In my case the exact error was:

```
Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer realm="<registry>", Basic realm="<registry>"
```

My npmrc file should connect to a private npm registry and looked like this:

```
registry=https://<private-registry>
//<private-registry>:_authToken=<token>
//<private-registry>:always-auth=true
```

The issue was that I needed to add the https:// protocol also to the second and third line and it worked. In the end it looked like this:

```
registry=https://<private-registry>
    //https://<private-registry>:_authToken=<token>
    //https://<private-registry>:always-auth=true
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30354186)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with our company registry configured in `.npmrc`

```
registry=https:<compnay-registry-url>
```

Node version : 16.10.0 
NPM version : 7.24.0

**Solution:**

Execute `npm login`

```
$ npm login
npm notice Log in on https:<registry-url>
Username: xxxx
Password:
Email: (this IS public) (xxxx)
Logged in as xxx on https:<registry-url>.
```

After this `.npmrc` got updated with

```
//<registry-url>/:_authToken=xxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install any package from your private repo and you are getting this error with  `npm i package_name`  command then

```
1. remove your package-lock.json from the the directory where to tried to create the package from 
2. reinstall dependencies: npm i
```

this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue caused by an **expired token** in the `.npmrc` file in my project directory. Sadly the error is very unspecific on what causes the auth error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, package-lock.json gets packages from an internal company feed and I was not authenticated to use it, so I needed to get rid of locally cached credentials first and then create the correct authentication file (.npmrc in users folder) for everything to work:

1. Delete .npmrc file from c:\users\alias folder
2. Delete .npmrc file from project folder
3. Run this command to install vsts-npm-auth package:

   `npm install -g vsts-npm-auth`
4. Add .npmrc file back to project folder
5. Run `npx vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc` to refresh the credentials ->
   this will create .npmrc file in users/alias folder with updated
   credentials

npm install and other commands works as expected

The reason we do #2 and #4 is that if we try to install packages without deleting this file, it would try to get the package from the internal feed, and fail.

Answer (score 0):

For me the the problem was in .npmrc file the key `password` needed to be changed to `_password` then `npm install` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using a **Mac** and Azure - it was because my Personal Access Token (PAT) had expired and it didn't let me know.

Open your `.npmrc` with your auth tokens in.

Go to your Azure repo and click your profile and then personal access tokens.

Create a new token.

Open terminal and run:

```
node -e "require('readline') .createInterface({input:process.stdin,output:process.stdout,historySize:0}) .question('PAT> ',p => { b64=Buffer.from(p.trim()).toString('base64');console.log(b64);process.exit(); })"
```

Paste your PAT in and press Enter

Copy the Base64 encoded value into your `.npmrc` password.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, deleting the `node_modules` directory and the `package-lock.json` file resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same error.
In my case, the initial project including `package-lock.json` file was composed with NodeJS version 12 and npm version 6.
But trying to run `npm install` on my local machine with NodeJS version 16 and npm version 7 was causing this problem.

My solution was installing dependencies with the initial version of NodeJS. I used docker to get the correct version, run this command from the root directory of your project (where the `package.json` file is located):

```
docker run --rm -it \
    -w /app \
    -v $PWD/:/app \
    node:12 \
    npm install
```

If you do not have docker installed, you can try using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. I just logged in again in NPM and the problem was solved

```
npm login
```

After you write your username and password execute again

```
npm install
```

Answer (score -1):

Just run `npm run reauthenticateNpmAuth`

It'll open an Azure login.
Use your Azure DevOps credentials to authenticate

Comment: `reauthenticateNpmAuth` is a script from yourself which isn't known to the reader. What is the script content @RoshanSamarasinghe? Should be in your package.json somewhere.