# npm ERR! code E401 npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

My Node version is 10.15.0 and NPM version is 6.8.4
On running npm install after upgrading
npm to 14.16.0 and npm to 7.6.2

Getting this error -

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/xyz/.npm/_logs/2021-04-15T18_55_07_993Z-debug.log
```

Comment: In my case, I fixed this issue by adding a new Private Access Token in Azure DevOps. Then I had to Base64 encode it and add it to .npmrc ...Maybe this approach helps somebody else as well.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

1. Try Deleting the package-lock.json file before running the command "npm install" after upgrading the node versions, if you have not done that.
2. If that will not work try removing the .npmrc file in $HOME directory as mentioned in this post.

[NPM ERR Code E401: Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894644/npm-err-code-e401-unable-to-authenticate-need-bearer-authorization)

Note - Deleting package-lock.json can have its own issues as mentioned in this posts, so go with this solution unless you find any better solution.

[Deleting `package-lock.json` to Resolve Conflicts quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124033/deleting-package-lock-json-to-resolve-conflicts-quickly?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Yep I totally missed that. Removing the package-lock.json worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124033/deleting-package-lock-json-to-resolve-conflicts-quickly#54127283) for potential reasons why you may not want to delete `package-lock.json`.

Comment: In my case, I fixed this issue by adding a new Private Access Token in Azure DevOps. Then I had to Base64 encode it and add it to .npmrc
...Maybe this approach helps somebody else as well.

Comment: Can you explain what's causing the issue in the first place?

Answer (score 12):

In the directory `C/Users/your-windows-username/`

delete the following files:

```
.cache
.package
.package-lock
.npmrc
```

After that, go to your project and run the following command in your terminal

```
npm i
```

Comment: I only found the .cache, but that and deleting the package-lock.json file fixed it.  Thank you. I would never in a million years have figured this one out.

Comment: clear .npmrc did the trick for me

Comment: Be careful blowing away your `.cache` directory, as it's used by `pip` and other package managers.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error with the company registry configured in `.npmrc`

```
registry=https:<company-registry-url>
```

Node version : 19.1.0 
NPM version : 8.19.3

**Solution:**

Execute `npm login`

```
$ npm login
npm notice Log in on https:<registry-url>
Username: xxxx
Password:
Email: (this IS public) (xxxx)
Logged in as xxx on https:<registry-url>.
```

After this `.npmrc` got updated with

```
//<registry-url>/:_authToken=xxxxx
```

Comment: Worked thanks! I had company npm artifactory registered at Jfrog.

Answer (score 5):

Your password in .npmrc must be base64 encoded. Easy to screw up just copy-pasting the password, need to base64 encode that.

Answer (score 3):

I have been getting the same error recently on various projects after running `npm run dev`:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
```

What fixed it for me was to delete my `package-lock.json` file (and any `yarn.lock` files, which might create conflicts with npm) and the `node_modules` directory. Then I updated my npm packages with `npm update`. (CAUTION: Before updating any npm packages, you should probably create a new Git branch and run `npm update` in that new branch. If you run into bigger problems after the updates, then you can revert back to your previous branch.)

After my packages were updated, then running my npm startup script (e.g. `npm run dev`) worked again without errors.

NOTE: You can run `npm outdated` to see which of your npm packages could use an update.

Answer (score 2):

If you configured your `.npmrc`, maybe your credentials are expired or need new credentials. Try this `vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc`. If it gives you this error **[The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.]**
try with `vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc -force`. That should generate new credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the specified log file (e. g. `/Users/xyz/.npm/_logs/2021-04-15T18_55_07_993Z-debug.log`). It could be that a 3rd party or corporate package to be installed requires authentication.

For example, if you try to install the pro icons of FontAwesome and the authentication (token) is missing, this error occurs.

Comment: This actually helped me and turned out to be my exact problem (hadn't copied the .npmrc file over) so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I encountered this error while dealing with the Azure Artifacts feed. By generating a new Personal Access Token (PAT) in Azure DevOps and using its Base64 encoded value in my `.npmrc` file, I was able to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Had the same issue with Node 16.x.x.**
I have done everything from this topic and those topics which were mentioned here and nothing helped me!

The only thing that helped me to login was that I **have deleted Node 16.x.x** and **installed Node 14.8.1** from here - **https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/**

Answer (score 0):

It can be happening because of a bug on npm. This was happening to me with npm v7. Switched to v6 and it worked.

More context: https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/2153

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

```
npm login    
npm notice Log in on https://www.SOME_URL.com
Username: xyz
Password:
Email: (this IS public) (USER_EMAIL_ID.com)
Logged in as xyz on https://www.SOME_URL.com
```

and then `npm login`. All dependencies installed

Answer (score -3):

Reinstall the lastest node.js. That fixed my issue.