# Getting error while i am trying to run "npm install"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, .npmrc

The below is the complete error what I am getting:

```
npm ERR! code E401 npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47, Basic realm="https://pkgsprodcus1.pkgs.visualstudio.com/", TFS-Federated
```

Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Add a list of packages that you are trying to install. You can get the list from `package.json`. It seems like you are trying to install a private package and you don't have the necessary authentication

Comment: Are you trying to install packages from private repository ?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894644/npm-err-code-e401-unable-to-authenticate-need-bearer-authorization

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue and this got fixed by running the below command.
Run the below command to remove the default registry

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

or

```
npm config delete registry
```

[NPM CONFIG DOCS](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-config)