# npm installing Font Awesome throws errors

Tags: node.js, npm, font-awesome

Wondering if anyone has come accross this issue, and if how, what's the fix?

trying to install fontawesome in npm. all my other packages are installed fine, but comes to font awesome and I get the errors below...

> PS C:\Users\sihar\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\Website_3.0> npm install --save
> @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
>
> npm ERR! code E401 npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password. npm ERR! If
> you were trying to login, change your password, create an npm ERR!
> authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then npm ERR!
> that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly. npm ERR!
> Please try again, or recover your password at: npm ERR!
> https://www.npmjs.com/forgot npm ERR! npm ERR! If you were doing some
> other operation then your saved credentials are npm ERR! probably out
> of date. To correct this please try logging in again with: npm ERR!
> npm login
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\sihar\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-05-20T04_04_20_871Z-debug-0.log

as always any assistance is appreciated.
Simon

Comment: Can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM ERR Code E401: Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894644/npm-err-code-e401-unable-to-authenticate-need-bearer-authorization)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by installing a previous version of npm.